# Looking for fantasy book series involving a ship and a rainbow

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel

I'm really upset because I thought I had remembered the title correctly only to find that I had somehow been thinking of The Voyage of the Dawn Treader which is not the series i'm looking for.

It's a children's/young adult series involving children going on myth themed adventures on a ship. I remember that in each one there is travel on a rainbow and that one of the books was based on Pandora's box which also featured a thunder bird at one point and another that is based on Irish faerie myths and specifically involves the Unseelie court.

This isn't a particularly old series I don't think, I remember reading the Unicorns of Balinor around the same time frame, but was at least early 2000's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could very well be *Voyage of the Basset*. It was written by James C. Christensen, with Renwick St. James and Alan Dean Foster. Later, the story was adapted into a novel, and the novel continued into a series, by Tanith Lee. It is that, I think, that you remember reading.

[image]
[image]

- *Voyage of the Basset* sounds similar to *Voyage of the Dawn Treader*. Indeed, there are some common themes between the two (a magical chain of islands).
- The [first book in the series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0679891277) features Pandora's Box.
- The [second book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0679891285) features the Unseelie Court.

  > Gwen Thornworth has dreamed of dancing with fairies since she was a
  >   little girl. When the Bassett arrives to pick her up, it looks like
  >   her dream will come true! Gwen's twin brother, Devin, reluctantly
  >   comes along to keep an eye on her. And he has to do just that when
  >   Gwen is lured away to the dark halls of the Unseelie fairies. Can
  >   Devin rescue his sister or will he also be caught under the spell of
  >   the Raven Queen? This second book in this thrilling new series that
  >   combines magic and mythology will captivate readers.
- I don't know whether there is a thunderbird, but [there *is* a Fire Bird](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0375811095).
- Travel is via rainbow:

  > "Our direction really is to be upward. We must ascend the rainbow."

Another possible confusion is *The Chronicles of the Imaginarium Geographica*. 
It is clear that James Owen was inspired by *Voyage of the Basset*, since *Here There Be Dragons*, the first book in the *Chronicles of the Imaginarium Geographica*, features a magical ship which can cross to a magical Archipelago The ship is crewed by fauns, there is a faerie isle of some sort near the entrance to the Archipelago, and Pandora's box has a prominent and sinister presence in the plot.

Yet to my knowledge, James Owen has never acknowledged that Lee or Christensen were among his inspirations.

Comment: YESSSSS!!! This is it! Now that I know the name again I can't believe I forgot the name. Thank you so much, this was literally what I was looking for and you are the best.